Windows Server 2016 DISM Repair
I Have a Server 2016 Data Center - the OS was corrupted by a faulty HDD (backup not available). I want to try to repair with DISM via Windows Recovery Environment. But can't get it to work.
I'm getting error 3 failed to initialize every time.
at CMD I type: DISM /image:D:\ /CleanUp-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E:\Sources\install.wim:4 /LimitAccess
From research - it seems very few people have ever been successful at getting this to work offline.
D = windows OS directory in RE E = ISO image of Server 2016 DC
Windows does not boot to Safemode or normally.
I also tried:
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=D:\ /offwindir=D:\windows
and I get: Windows resource protection could not start the repair service.
I have tried booting from the built in Recovery Environment and from the installation media (ISO image) without any success.

Windows does not boot does it hang? Blue screen?

It hangs on windows logo and spinning wheel
